# In django template how to retain Dropdown selected option after submit?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

There is a dropdown to select country and then show results in the same page after submitting it.
Here is the code for the dropdown:

```
            <form type="get" action=".">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label class="m-12">Contry</label>
                <select name = "drop1" >
                    <option value="England">England</option>
                    <option value="USA">USA</option>
                    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                </select>
                <input class="btn btn-side-bar" type = "submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

After pressing the button, it does query and return the result to the same page. The page is reloaded so the dropdown does not show the selected item but the default option.

The url shows the selected option in it.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/lookup/?searchfield=USA
```

The dropdown should show the selected value but it does not. How this problem can be fixed? An idea is to get the value from the url. Or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Use a [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-form-class) class or a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) if it is for a model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your view take country as a variable and pass to template.
In template set the option value of that variable.